# Prove that there is no selection scheme that can be guaranteed to always work with less than one trillion coin flips

Tags: probability

I was trying to do the following probability homework:

You must select one of the three agents to carry a dangerous mission, but your only source of randomness is a single fair coin.

(a) Devise a scheme so that each agent has probability $1/3$ of being selected.

(b) Using your scheme, what is the average number of coin flips required to reach a decision?

(c) Prove that there is no selection scheme that can be guaranteed to always work with less than one trillion coin flips.

I solved part (a) and (b) without difficulties. But I couldn't solve (c) and I do not understand the solution:

With any fixed number of flips $n$, there are exactly $2^n$ possible outcomes, each with equal probability. Since $3$ does not divide $2^n$, there is no event in this sample space with probability $1/3$.

I understand the logic above. What I don't understand, is how the above implies there is no scheme that can be guaranteed to always work with less than one trillion coin flips? Why the non-existence of an event with probability $1/3$ implies there is no scheme with the desired properties?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I think the key is what does "guaranteed to always work with less than one trillion coin flips" mean exactly. My understanding is that it means P(reach a decision with less than one trillion coin flips)=1. And if that's the case, I don't understand why the non-existence of an event with probability $1/3$ implies non-existence of such schemes.

Comment: By definition, a perfect selection would mean an event with *exact* probability $\frac 13$.  As you have remarked, there is no such event that you can build with a finite number of coin tosses.

Comment: @lulu I am sorry but even we if did have an event with probability 1/3, isn't possible that it doesn't work with less than one trillion coin flips? Cuz the probability that the event doesn't happen is 2/3 and it doesn't happen one trillion times is non-zero? Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what point you are making.  For any finite number of tosses, it's easy to see that you can't construct an event of exact probability $\frac 13$.  So the claim is true for a trillion tosses, or a billion trillion, or whatever.  No selection process can be exact.  Of course, you can have one that is very, very close.

Comment: @Ishigami the point here is that *in the worst case scenario* we might not have been able to choose.  Sure, in a best case scenario we can be done very quickly (*flip a coin three times... if the three results are not the same, consider the one toss that was different than the other two.  the corresponding agent is the selection.  If all three flips were the same, try again*).  Sure, with high probability you will have made a selection very quickly... but there is that chance that if you get the worst luck possible that you will be stuck repeating the process a billion times without result.

Comment: lulu @JMoravitz I guess what I am confused is, I don't understand why if there exists an event $E$ such that $P(E)=1/3$, there it would mean P(reach a conclusion with less than 1 trillion flips) = 1, like we could have the case (2/3)^1 trillion. Eg: the scheme in (a): flip the coin twice, and uses outcomes TH, HT and HH to choose among the agents, in the case of TT, flip again. In this case, we could keep getting TT so it can't be guaranteed to work with less than 1 trillion flips. But even if there is such an event, how can we construct a scheme such that it will be guaranteed to work?

Comment: You must have misread the statement.  P(reach a conclusion with less than 1 trillion flips) is **not** equal to $1$.  We can **not** construct a scheme such that it will be guaranteed to work.  Again, this is precisely because of what was noted before already, that $2^n$ is coprime to $3$

Comment: You can represent the sample space as a perfect binary tree. Any select scheme means is equivalent to we are placing different selections on different tree nodes. After a certain number of flips, i.e. tree with a certain depth $n$, a guaranteed selection means all $2^n$ leaf nodes are placed with the selection without indecision. Since you cannot partition the $2^n$ leaf nodes into $3$ groups such that they are equally likely, there must be some indecision leaf nodes at any level - otherwise your selection scheme is unfair, violating condition a).

Comment: To expand on JMoravitz last comment, the claim "(there exists an event $E$, involving only finitely many flips, such that $P(E) = \frac 13$) implies $P($reach a conclusion with less than 1 trillion flips$)$" is not one the problem, nor any of the commentors, have made. Until now. That claim is true. But the reason it is true is that there is no such event $E$, and the statement "$A \implies B$" is true when $A$ is false, regardless of $B$. Now, if you were to allow $E$ to involve infinitely many flips, the claim would be false, as such an $E$ does exist, but the conclusion is still false.